# jQuery function works in chrome but not other browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

So I am trying to make a form correct a phone number after the user types in their number.

For example the form will only let them type numbers, nothing else. 
So when they type 1234567890 it will reformat it to (123) 456-7890 on the focusout.

If I was to run it in a another browser it shows up as ((12) 3) -456- because it re-runs the code again after the focusout so it does it twice.

I was able to do this fine on chrome, but it doesn't work in any other browsers.

Here is my code:

```
$('#number').focusin(number_remove);
$('#number').keyup(number_check);
$('#number').focusout(number_add);

    function number_remove() {
    var number = $('#number').val();
    var newnumber = number.replace(/\D/g,'');
    $('#number').val(newnumber);
}

function number_check() {
    var number = $('#number').val();
    if(number != '') {
        var newnumber = number.replace(/\D/g,'');
        $('#number').val(newnumber);
        if(number.length >= 10) {
            $('#number').css('background', 'rgba(54, 255, 0, 0.1)');
        }else{
            $('#number').css('background', 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1)');
        }
    }else{
        $('#number').css('background', 'rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.1)');
    }
}

function number_add() {
    var number = $('#number').val();
    if(number != ''){
        var numbersub1 = number.substring(0, 3);
        var numbersub2 = number.substring(3, 6);
        var numbersub3 = number.substring(6, 10);
        var finalnumber = '('+numbersub1+') '+numbersub2+'-'+numbersub3;
        $('#number').val(finalnumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: @DyrandzFamador In other browsers if I typed 1234567890 it shows up at ((12) 3) -456- when it ran the function.

Comment: idk, works in my mozilla http://jsfiddle.net/cuw303dy/1/

Comment: If I add a delay I found out it works on every browser actually but it wasn't working in firefox or safari for me..I don't know why

Comment: In the fiddle from the comment, it doesn't work in your browsers? (there're no delays)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I have made some changes to your code. Basically what I did is I have attached an event to the textbox using On http://api.jquery.com/on/

And for avoiding focus out to fire multiple times in other browsers I have added e.stopPropagation();

You can find the working example on http://jsfiddle.net/3v1mmepo/5/

```
$('#number').on("focus", function () {
    var number = $(this).val();
    var newnumber = number.replace(/\D/g, '');
    $(this).val(newnumber);
});

$('#number').on("keyup", function () {
    var number = $(this).val();
    if (number != '') {
        var newnumber = number.replace(/\D/g, '');
        $(this).val(newnumber);
        if (number.length >= 10) {
            $(this).css('background', 'rgba(54, 255, 0, 0.1)');
        } else {
            $(this).css('background', 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1)');
        }
    } else {
        $(this).css('background', 'rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.1)');
    }
});

$('#number').on("focusout", function (e) {
    var number = $(this).val();
    if (number != '') {
        var numbersub1 = number.substring(0, 3);
        var numbersub2 = number.substring(3, 6);
        var numbersub3 = number.substring(6, 10);
        var finalnumber = '(' + numbersub1 + ') ' + numbersub2 + '-' + numbersub3;
        $(this).val(finalnumber);
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```